# Splitting string by parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like `abcdef(1)ghijkllskjdflkjsdfsdf(2)aslkdjfjgls(3)jgjgjkdkgkdll`

I want to split it into `n` number of lines depending on occurences of `(n)` in the string.

For example in above string, following is acheived :

```
lines [0] = abcdef
lines [1] = ghijkllskjdflkjsdfsdf
lines [2] = aslkdjfjgls
lines [3] = jgjgjkdkgkdll.
```

**What i am trying is :**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

var pattern = @"((.*))"; 

string[] lines = Regex.Split(text,pattern);

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}

string FinalText = sb.ToString();
```

**Can anyone help with C# regular expressions or string split function ?**

Thank you.

Comment: for future RegEx generation: http://www.txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3

Answer (score 4):

```
string pattern = @"\(\d+\)";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(text,pattern);
string finalText = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

The follow regex will match your numbered brackets:

```
\(\d+\)
```

Your usage of Regex.Split is correct, so I do not know why you need help with that!?